# What is wrong in this short line of code in R

Tags: r

I have an m-by-23 matrix 'temp' in R, let's say m=100.  When I run the short code below , I get the error
"Error in temp[i, 2:23] : subscript out of bounds"

In the console when I check for the values of j and i, I get 1 and 101 respectively. That tells me the index went over 100, but I don't see what is possible wrong in this command.

```
  for(j in 1:nrow(temp)-1){
    for(i in j+1:nrow(temp)){
      if(identical(temp[j,2:23],temp[i,2:23])){
      #Do something
       }
     }
    
   }
```

Goal:The goal is to count how many of each unique row there are in the matrix (count repeating rows). I believe there is possibly an easier way to do this, I will appreciate any suggestions. Thank you

I tried to take it a loop at a time, and the error seem to occur when I add the if statement.

Answer (score 2):

The problem happens at the statement `j+1:nrow(temp)`, which should be `(j+1):nrow(temp)`

Two expressions definitely give different output. For example

```
> (2 + 1):5
[1] 3 4 5

> 2 + 1:5
[1] 3 4 5 6 7
```

When you read the [precedence of operators in R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html), you will see that `:` has higher precedence than addition `+`

[image]

Comment: I see, I that makes sense.  I thought I was going crazy for a minute. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

And probably also around the first `for`-statement:

```r
d <- mtcars[1:5, ]
for (i in 1:nrow(d) - 1) {
  print(i)
}
#> [1] 0
#> [1] 1
#> [1] 2
#> [1] 3
#> [1] 4
for (i in 1:(nrow(d) - 1)) {
  print(i)
}
#> [1] 1
#> [1] 2
#> [1] 3
#> [1] 4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop's logic is effectively `1:nrow(iris)-1 + 1:nrow(iris)`. Put `cat(j,i,"\n")` as the #do to observe output.

R has a built in method that identifies duplicate rows:

`duplicated()` identifies the 2nd (3rd, etc) duplicate (not the first observation, as that one is not the duplicate; but you can `fromLast` to go in reverse)

```
?duplicated
duplicated(iris)
table(duplicated(iris))

iris[duplicated(iris),]
iris[duplicated(iris, fromLast = TRUE),] #
```

Comment: This is helpful. After locating the duplicate rows, I want to add up the values in their first column, I believe I can add a few lines to this function to do that.

Comment: I've added some more details

Comment: Thank you for the addition.
So this is what I want;  Column 1 of each row contains  a number, and for any row say k,  I want to compare the vector temp[k, 2:end] to all the other rows temp[j, 2:end], and it I find a match, I want to add the numbers in their first columns temp[k,1]+temp[I,1] and assign this new value to row temp[k,1] and delete the entire row j. I am not sure how to accomplish that yet

Comment: You should post that as a new question. Include what you have so far, and a small dummy sample data for input and desired output.

Comment: Got it!  Will do

Comment: @J.Kyei Let me know when you post, I've got a tidyverse solution in mind